# How can I start a subscript within a perpetually running bash script after a specific string has been printed in the terminal output?

Tags: bash

**Specifics:**

I'm trying to build a bash script which needs to do a couple of things.

Firstly, it needs to run a third party script that I cannot manipulate. This script will build a project and then start a node server which outputs data to the terminal continually. This process needs to continue indefinitely so I can't have any exit codes.

Secondly, I need to wait for a specific line of output from the first script, namely 'Started your app.'.

Once that line has been output to the terminal, I need to launch a separate set of commands, either from another subscript or from an if or while block, which will change a few lines of code in the project that was built by the first script to resolve some dependencies for a later step.

So, how can I capture the output of the first subscript and use that to run another set of commands when a particular line is output to the terminal, all while allowing the first script to run in the terminal, and without using timers and without creating a huge file from the output of subscript1 as it will run indefinitely?

Pseudo-code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script needs to stay running & will output to the terminal (at some point)
#     a string that we need to wait/watch for to launch subscript2
sh subscript1

# This can't run until subscript1 has output a particular string to the terminal
# This could be another script, or an if or while block
sh subscript2
```

I have been beating my head against my desk for hours trying to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You lost me at "without using file-watching". Where is that requirement from?

Comment: Also, you should probably investigate whether it's really true that this third-party script can't be changed. The script is clearly not designed with programmatic invocation in mind; hacking around that is a recipe for headaches, especially if you do it without talking to the script vendor, because they're obviously not expecting to have to preserve all of the details you're making hardcoded assumptions about.

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more clear about the file-watching thing. What I mean is I don't want the output from subscript1 dumping into a file un-checked, as that subscript will run indefinitely. I'm totally fine with a temporary file to house a small portion of the output if that will get the job done. I'll amend the question. As to the third-party script, it is definitely not something I can mess with. :/

Comment: Re: "As to the third-party script, it is definitely not something I can mess with": OK, but "not something I can mess with" does not mean "something that *no one* can modify". If you have some sort of business relationship with the vendor of that script (e.g., your employer is a customer of that vendor), then that relationship should include a conduit for requesting necessary changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bad idea — much better to have `subscript1` changed to be automation-friendly — but in theory you can write:

```
sh subscript1 \
| {
    while IFS= read -r line ; do
      printf '%s\n' "$line"
      if [[ "$line" = 'Started your app.' ]] ; then
        sh subscript2 &
        break
      fi
    done
    cat
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @ruakh, I was able to modify this for my use case and it worked like a charm. I did end up removing the break though as the first subscript was failing with 'Error: write EPIPE' which may be a node thing. Thanks again!

Comment: @BS: You're welcome! Re: "the first subscript was failing with 'Error: write EPIPE'": That probably means you removed the `cat` by mistake.

Comment: I revisited this script this morning after reading your latest response @ruakh. I had tested it with & without both the break and the cat in various combinations... it was working without either (but obviously wasn't killing the loop). I'm embarrassed to admit this but I had forgotten the curlies surrounding the 'while' block. I have added them now and it's working perfectly, break & cat included.

Comment: @BS: Re: "it was working without either (but obviously wasn't killing the loop)": Yeah, the `break`+`cat` aren't strictly necessary, but they ensure that you don't run `subscript2` more than once, and they're also likely to allow subsequent output (after the `Started your app.` line) to reach the console somewhat more efficiently than otherwise (since `cat` is much more efficient than a pure-Bash `read`+`printf` loop).